# Render react app inside a plain html project?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have the following problem.

I created a bunch of plain html/css/js pages to do the landing of my webpage due to the fact that i didn't feel necessary to add react to them, due to the fact that all the data there is static.

Now i want to create all the login and inner app stuff, is there a way to keep the plain html files and have a react project at the same time?

My idea is something like create the react app, send all the plain files to the public files and, instead of starting the app in the index.html file given by react, start my app in my home.html file (one of the static files i created), but i don´t know if that is even possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can have a react app running anywhere really. You can also use JSX, although you would need a transpiler for it like babel. So here is an example of a React app right here within my answer:

```html
<html>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin>
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <div>This is a static component</div>
  <br /><br />

  <div id="root"></div>
 
 <script type="text/babel">
  
    const App = () => {
      return (
        <div>Hello, this is a ReactJS component!</div>
      )
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
        <App />,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
  </script>
 
  </body>
```

Just give it a try right here. This can allow you have a website where any random page can be powered by React, while others may or may not. React is pretty pliable like that.