# ASP.NET Project with React problem with web compiler 2022+ - Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, typescript

i have created a asp.net project (VB.Net) and i created many .jsx files that are compiles to js files from the extension WebCompiler 2022+

The problem here is that i got always this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined" ( in the js file its this code where the error came from ) "Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });"

i dont know how to handle it, it would be grateful if someone can help me.

here is the HTML file, where i bind the js files

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/style.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/components/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/components/node_modules/react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css" />

   <script src="/scripts/reControls/babel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="/scripts/reControls/react.development.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="/scripts/reControls/react-dom.development.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script src="/components/functions.js" type="module"></script>
   <script src="/components/login.js" type="module"></script>
   <script src="/components/index.js" type="module"></script>
   <script src="/components/app.js" type="module"></script>

   <title>Kundenportal - GSG</title>
</head>
<body>
   <script type="text/javascript">App();</script>
   <div id="root">

   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the app.jsx file

```
import React from 'react';
import Login from './login';

function App()
{
       return <Login />;
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the things are fine, but you need to use react DOM,

```
    ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Please check this answer
[Render react app inside a plain html project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66021222/render-react-app-inside-a-plain-html-project)